# PHP: looping through and parsing an array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, loops

I have created a simple blog app where all content are retrieved from database and trying to be parsed on my page. I have the 'main' page where all posts would be visible thus I select all posts from database and trying to parse them.

So while retrieve all data I pass them into an array where I endup with this:

```
var_dump($feed);
```

Gives me this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(5) { ["url"]=> string(9) "firstpost" ["baseurl"]=> string(6) "myblog" ["title"]=> string(22) "super awesome new post" ["publish"]=> string(20) "7 Jan 2014, 10:10 am" ["content"]=> string(419) "<p>sdfasjkgasg</p> <p>asdfg</p> <p>as</p> <p>dgsdg</p> <p><strong>this bold text</strong></p> <p>this is <em>italic</em></p> <p> </p> <ol> <li><em>skata q</em></li> <li><em>skata 2</em></li> <li><em>skata 3</em></li> </ol>" } [1]=> array(5) { ["url"]=> string(6) "POST_2" ["baseurl"]=> string(6) "myblog" ["title"]=> string(7) "Title 2" ["publish"]=> string(21) "25 Dec 2013, 10:58 am" ["content"]=> string(343) "<p>This is a plain text.</p> <p><strong>Here goes the bold text.</strong></p> <p><em>Oh and we got some Italic aswell.</em></p> <p>You know you can words too?</p> <p> </p> <p> </p> <p>And here we got some bulletings:</p>" } [2]=> array(5) { ["url"]=> string(6) "POST_3" ["baseurl"]=> string(6) "myblog" ["title"]=> string(24) "Super-awesome cool title" ["publish"]=> string(21) "25 Dec 2013, 10:47 am" ["content"]=> string(904) "<p>This is a plain text.</p> <p> </p> <p><strong>Here goes the bold text.</strong></p> <p> </p> <p><em>Oh and we got some Italic aswell.</em></p> <p> </p> <p>You know you can <span style="text-decoration: underline;">underline</span> words too?</p> <p> </p> <p><span style="text-decoration: line-through;">Or strikeout. Cool huh?</span></p> <p> </p> <p>And here we got some bulletings:</p> <ul> <li>First</li> <li>Second</li> <li>Third</li> </ul> <p>and of course, numbering:</p> <ol> <li>Number 1</li> <li>Number 2</li> <li>Number 3!</li> </ol> <p> </p>" } }
```

So now I am trying to parse each of those as such:

```
foreach ($feed as $obj) {
   echo "<div>URL:".$obj->url."</div>";
}
```

With no results. So I tried dumping `$obj->url` and I got this:

```
URL:NULL NULL NULL
```

How can I parse each data from the above array?

Comment: Hint: It's an array, not an object.

Comment: If you want to access it as an object, then you can covert it to an object: `$pbj = (object)$obj;`

Comment: It's not, just saying, that it can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it like this.

```
foreach ($feed as $obj) {
   echo "<div>URL:".$obj['url']."</div>";
}
```

You are accessing the array as an object. Do `$obj['url']` instead of `$obj->url` as shown.

Comment: Thank you. This works. Could you please explain how my trial wasn't working? I took it from the php.net

Comment: @ATs: Objects can be accessed as arrays, but arrays **can not** be accessed as objects. You were using the object notation to retrieve the URL and that's incorrect. Use the array syntax, i.e.: `$arr['url']`.